# diagonalizing a matrix with random elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-variables

Consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} cY & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ (That is, $Y \sim U(0,1)$). What conditions must $c$ have so that $A$ is stable?

---

We say that a matrix $A$ is stable if the eigenvalues, $\lambda$, are such that $|\lambda_i| \leq 1$. For the matrix $A$, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = cY$. For the matrix to be stable, since $Y \sim U(0,1)$, then $cY \sim U(0, c)$.

Is it correct to say that when $c$ should be in the interval $[0,1]$? or $[-1,1]$?

Or if you have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is $|cY|=|c|\cdot |Y| \le 1$; knowing that $|Y|\le 1$ and that the boundary can be reached, it is necessary and sufficient to have $|c|\le 1$.

So your second answer, $[-1,1]$, is correct.